# Are locks necessary in Node.js when using child processes in a manager / worker pattern to ensure thread safety?

Tags: node.js, multithreading, thread-safety, child-process

I am writing a simple, message-based manager / worker (http://lya.fciencias.unam.mx/jloa/patrones/MW.html) module for Node. Typically, in multi-threaded environments, code that modifies data would need a lock to prevent other threads from changing the data mid-routine, resulting in confusing race conditions. For example:

```
function assignWork(job) {
    if (!this.isWorkComplete && this.workerQueue.length != 0) {
        this.workerQueue.pop().runJob(job);
    }
}
```

The above code, in a multi-threaded environment, would require a lock, as it is possible that another thread would empty the worker queue between the time that this thread checks that it is populated and the time that it pops the worker off the queue, resulting in an error.

It is my understanding, however, that because Node uses a single event queue, it is impossible for synchronous code to have this aforementioned problem, as only a single thread is executed at once.

Is this assumption correct? Moreover, if it is correct for Node, do other implementations exist that use multiple threads and would require locking mechanism to ensure thread-safety?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the Node 6.0.0 documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_cluster):

> A single instance of Node.js runs in a single thread. To take
>   advantage of multi-core systems the user will sometimes want to launch
>   a cluster of Node.js processes to handle the load.

Javascript is single-threaded, so there are no thread-safety issues in any current, correct javascript engine.

The only true multi-threading we have in Javascript so far is Web workers. These use message passing to communicate, so they are not sharing memory (at least not visibly to the javascript developer; the engine might).

Race conditions are still very much possible in a single-threaded environment. Callbacks can be tricky.

Comment: My understanding is that Node's child_process works similarly... from [link](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html): "It is important to keep in mind that spawned Node.js child processes are independent of the parent with exception of the IPC communication channel that is established between the two. Each process has it's own memory, with their own V8 instances." The issue I've described, however, doesn't involve child processes editing data in the Manager (because of the lack of shared memory, they can't), and the function I'd need to lock is synchronous. In this case, is it thread-safe?

Comment: Anything you do in Javascript is thread-safe, but you might still end up with race conditions if you are fiering multiple events. So yes, it is thread-safe. Always.

Comment: Though that isn't so true anymore because SharedArrayBuffer does share memory, even between several worker threads. Though the worker-API is considered experimental in NodeJS, I think it stays because the demand is high.

The only safe options for sharing objects are ArrayBuffer (does also share memory, but gets invalidated on the sender's side) and of course MessagePorts (though they only allow communication between to workers, not arbitrary many).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Filip is absolutely right, Node.js though internally multi-threaded, provides a single thread interface to run the javascript code, and thereby every operation is thread safe. I did not come across any scenarios of race conditions, justified by the fact that there is no second party in the system to race with. For that matter please also note that the 'usual suspects' in the shared data manipulation logic (such as synchronize, mutex, volatile, monitor, barrier, semaphore etc.) are absent in the language semantics itself. Hope this gives you sufficient evidence, and confidence.

Bottom line is that Node programmer will not worry about cluttered access (multi-thread) instead about un-ordered (asynchronous) access to data.